# Get specified bit in addition of two large binary numbers

Tags: arrays, integers, binary-arithmetic

I am performing an addition operation on two large binary numbers that have an equal number of bits. Both numbers are stored in an array of length $N$, which is rather large.

At first I tried running a loop over them and keeping track of carry bits. This wasted time, because the aim is to get the bit at a specific position in this sum.

So I modified my approach in following way. Starting from the specified index, I am looping until I find a 0 bit in same position on both numbers; I add only those parts to each other and return the bit at the specified position.

This seems okay, but is this the best I can do? Recall that I want to get the value of one specific bit of the sum, given by its position.

Answer (score 3):

Your method will indeed work, but for two $n$-bit numbers it will still take $O(n)$ time. There is a much faster way to solve your problem, with running time $\Theta(\log n)$, known as **carry-lookahead addition**. The downside is that in my experience teaching this technique, people have a hard time wrapping their heads around it. You can find online sources, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-lookahead_adder) and [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/.../lookahead.html), and some algorithm or computer organization texts cover it. It's a really interesting algorithm, well worth taking the time to figure it out.

Comment: Sounds cool... Let me implement it first and examine the performance. For sure it will be fast enough but i am not at all interested in all the bits.

Comment: @Ravi Right, and that'll save you some time. Obviously, you don't have to pay any attention to higher-order bits than the one position you're looking at.

Comment: @Ravi. p.s., If you're going to implement this on a real machine, remember that although carry-lookahead addition is a natural candidate for recursion, function calls take a *lot* of time. It's often best to implement a non-recursive version.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ and $y$ denote the two numbers and $x_i$ and $y_i$ the i-th bits
in their respective binary representations. You want to determine the 
$i$-th bit in the binary representation of $x+y$.  You are not
interested in anything else.  If so, proceed as follows.

1. Compute $z = x_i \oplus y_i$.
2. Examine in succession $(x_{i-1},y_{i-1}), (x_{i-2}, y_{i-2}), \ldots$
   until you find a pair that is $(0,0)$ or $(1,1)$. If you reach $(x_0, y_0)$
   and all pairs have been either $(0,1)$ or $(1,0)$, stop. The answer is $z$.
3. If you find a pair $(x_j, y_j) = (0,0)$, stop. The answer is $z$.
   If instead $(x_j, y_j) = (1,1)$, stop. The answer is $1-z$ or the bit complement
   of $z$.

Comment: You will not believe me at all that the same thing i just concluded from binary numbers. Lets me implement it. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Edited??? What is the modification?

Comment: (a) I have no reason to disbelieve that you came up with the same idea all by yourself. (b) I deleted a word "if" which made no grammatical sense. If you want to see **exactly** what change was made, click on the link that says "edited 15 mins ago" or "edited 3 hours ago" or something similar, and it will show you _all_ the changes made since I first posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what language you're using to do this.  For instance, if this were C, I wouldn't use arrays. I would use Bitfields.  Then I'd have access to Bitfield operations.  Simple arithmetic is then done by using a combination of AND, OR, XOR and so on.

As far as I know, your Bitfield length will still be limited to your processor's and/or compiler's capacity, without additional libraries.

Also, this question should have been posted in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Each specific bit in the sum of two $n$-bit numbers $A=a_{n}a_{n-1}...a_{1}$ and $B=b_{n}b_{n-1}...b_{1}$ is given by the sum of the corresponding bits in the addends, plus a possible carry of $1$, modulo $2$.  The carry is $1$ if the less-significant neighbor bits are $11$, or if they are $01$ or $10$ and subjected to a carry themselves.
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
(A+B)_{k}&=&(A_{k} \oplus B_{k}) \oplus \text{carry}_{k}(A,B) \\
\text{carry}_{k+1}(A,B)&=&(A_{k}\wedge B_{k})\vee((A_{k}\oplus B_{k})\wedge\text{carry}_{k}) \\
\text{carry}_{1}(A,B)&=&0
\end{eqnarray}
$$
(Here $\oplus$ means addition modulo $2$.)  If the numbers are random, you can expect this to take $O(1)$ time, whereas calculating the sum is certainly $\Theta(n)$.  (As a practical matter, though, integer addition is so highly optimized that you will need $n$ to be very large before realizing any speed gain.)